# How to export data from multiple tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to query two tables and export data in csv format. When I click on export it only exports data from one table.

Eg:

```
select table1.xyz,table2.abc from table1 join table2 on table1.pqr=table2.pqr
```

But only 1 table data is getting exported.

Answer (score 1):

Are you clicking the right "export" link? I think you are clicking the "Export" tab that show you the export for the actual selected table.

The one you must click is the one below the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you, for instance, want only tables with a certain prefix, you can filter the tables view in phpmyadmin:

[image: phpmyadmin filter]

Then you scroll down and hit "Check All" and then "With Selected" > "Export".

[image: phpmyadmin export]

Click "OK" and get your SQL file.